# Keeping leading 0 when getting a form value with JQuery?

Tags: jquery, forms, processing, leading-zero

I keep loosing my leading 0 from a phone number field on my user sign-up form.  I use JQuery to get the value of the fields, then send them to a processing page via Get.

My phone number fields are split into 3 parts.  The third input field looks like this:

```
<input name="phone3" type="tel" id="phone3" class="TextField30" maxlength="4" required>
```

I also tried having the type as text.

My jQuery for this field looks like this:

```
$p3=""+$('#phone3').val();
```

I also tried $p3=""+$('#phone3').attr('value'); since I thought that accessing it via the attribute meant that it would leave it as a string instead of converting it to a number.

Comment: Check [this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Z6M6q/1/); it shows that value is collected correctly. How exactly you check that this leading 0 is lost?

Comment: I was checking when the value was re-displayed in the table I setup to view the records.  Your comment got me thinking, though, so I checked the MySQL database that the record is stored in and the fields were set as "tinyint" instead of "char".  Once I changed them to "char" it worked fine!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured out the issue actually wasn't in the html or jQuery - it was that the field in the MySQL database was set to "tinyint" instead of "char". $p3=$('#phone3').val(); worked fine once the MySQL field type was corrected!

Answer (score 0):

try to store to a variable like this.

```
var phone = $('#phone3').val();
```

Comment: Not sure why, but that made the form stop responding all together when I clicked to save it.  I figured out the issue actually wasn't in the html or jQuery, though.  It was that the field in the MySQL database was set to "tinyint" instead of "char".  Thank you for the suggestion!

Comment: So it was not related to jQuery.

Comment: I thought it was from the early forum-searching that I did, but in the end simply having $p3=$('#phone3').val(); worked fine once the MySQL field type was corrected!

Comment: Thanks for fixing my original post.  I've only posted on here once or twice before and couldn't remember how to correctly format the code I was posting!